# How to get search time in haystack-solr

Tags: django, solr, django-haystack

How can I get the time it takes for a searching a query in haystack using `solr` at the backend? I want to get this time and display it on my template. Something similar to what google shows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some digging as best as I can work out it is not currently possible to access the query time (QTime) from SOLR using Haystack.

The pysolr object has the QTime attached to it.
https://github.com/toastdriven/pysolr/blob/master/pysolr.py#L265

However this information is not extracted from the object by Haystack.
https://github.com/toastdriven/django-haystack/blob/master/haystack/backends/solr_backend.py#L313

In _process_results() raw_results is a pysolr object however you can see that qtime is not returned.
https://github.com/toastdriven/django-haystack/blob/master/haystack/backends/solr_backend.py#L382